# Sample-rate tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-request

I think this site would benefit from a [sample-rate](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample-rate) tag. I just started using it and posted a sample rate related question and couldn't find a fitting tag to use.

Also I think there should be a [tag-request](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-request) tag, as can be seen on many other meta sites on SE.

Comment: I tagged your [question](http://avp.stackexchange.com/q/8258/2569) with [tag:sample-rate].